# Xamarin Forms System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, model-binding

Hey I am new to Xamarin Forms and I somehow don't see through that binding thing.

Here is the Code where I set the BindingContext:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new GameViewModel();
}
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    private Team Team1 { get; set; }
    public Team Team2 { get; set; }

    public string Team1Name { get { return Team1.Name; } }
    public string StaticString { get { return "static"; } }

}
```

StaticString is working, Binding Team1.Name is displaying nothing and Team1Name is throwing the exception.

And here is the View:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Entry Placeholder="{Binding Team1.Name}" />
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Entry Placeholder="{Binding Team1Name}" />
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

The Exception I get is

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

Comment: `Team1` is null.  You've declared it but haven't instantiated it.  `Team1` is also private, and you can only bind to public properties

Comment: @Jason thx a lot, i forgot to initialize Team....

Comment: You can write your solution in the answer and mark it which will help more people with same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jasons comment I figured out that i forgot to initialize the Team class. Unfortunately the error message I got from Xamarin wasn't that helpful.